# Book recomendation for function sequences.

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, self-learning, book-recommendation

I wanted to study about sequences of functions defined in metric spaces. What book/books do you recommend? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Any good internediate level real analysis text will have this material. The traditional book is of course-*ick*-Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. You don't read Rudin,you do battle with it. A much more pleasant and informative book in my opinion at the same level is Charles Chapman Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis*-which I affectionately refer to as Rudin Done Right. As I've said elsewhere, Pugh has a real gift: He seems to know exactly how many words it takes to explain something- not one word more, not one word less. If you were my student and you came to me with that question, that's the book I'd recommend.

Comment: "You don't read Rudin, you do battle with it." - Nice one!